# AVERAGEIF on multiple work sheets (via 3D Reference) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a question when using excel averageif functions:
I have a workbook containing monthly information (stored as numerical values) in 12 different worksheets (named Jan, Feb,..., Dec). In each worksheet, I calculate the sum, e.g. `=SUM(B1:B100)` and store it in cell A1.

I create an overview worksheet which takes average of each month's A1 values, and I want to exclude those with 0.

I use the formula

```
=AVERAGEIF(Jan:Dec!A1, ">0")
```

however, I got `#VALUE!` using this averageif function.

What is the cause of this problem? Can't the range of AVERAGEIF be the result from another SUM function?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a 3D reference in Averageif, or SumIf for that matter.  Your 3D refernce is Jan:Dec!A1, that is, you aren't referencing a range on a single worksheet (which would be 2D) you are referencing a range on multiple sheets.

See the following link for a list of acceptable functions to use 3D references in.
[Create a 3D Reference, Microsoft Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-HP010102346.aspx)

You will have to come up with a different way.  The above answers you specific question. I can add a recommendation in the comments if you desire.

Comment: One thing to note about using 3D references, though; if you move around sheets or delete sheets you can royally mess up the reference.  For small sets of data, you'd be safer to just statically list each cell in the equation.

Comment: generally speaking, I want to skip the columns with 0 when calculating average, therefore I need selection conditions using averageif. But it seems that the 3D reference functions cannot satisfy my need.

Comment: I was thinking about your problem.  If you don't to want consolidate the data, you could do the following: Next to each sum on the month pages (assumed to be in cell a1) in cell b1, you could use the following: `=if(a1=0,0,1)`  Then for your formula in the main, summarizing, page you do: `=sum(Jan:Dec!a1)/sum(Jan:Dec!b1)`  This will get around it for sure and easily.  If you can't do b1 for your "if" formula, just place it somehwere else, consistently on all monthly pages and replace the b1, above, with that cell.  Lots of options open to you!  Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

I would consolidate all the data into one Table on one Sheet.  I would add a column for Month/Date if required to identify the rows.

Then your formula will be easy, and any other kind of analysis or reporting will also be easy.  You wont have to worry about keeping multiple sheets in sync.

Comment: Although what you've written is correct, it doesn't answer the question, should've been posted as a comment.